# Window location in ajax in if statement

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have tried to put an echo if the sql insert is success.

```
   echo "success" //sql insert is success

   else {echo "error message"}

   //Everything is ok here.
```

I want to return it to ajax. If the sql "success" and it echo "success" then it will redirect the page to another page.  But my code bellow is redirect it to another page no matter it echo success or error message.

```
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success:function(html)
            {
                if (html=='success')
                    {
                    alert (html);
                    window.location=''
                    }

                else {
                    alert (html);
                    //Just stay here, don't go anywhere/ 
                    }
            }
        });
```

Comment: You probably have a form that submits, otherwise there's no reason why it would redirect to some other page ?

Comment: You must echo your output in JSON form using `json_encode(array())` to get the proper output using key and value

Comment: @adeneo: it just redirect it to the `window.location='infistallLocation.php'`

Comment: But the alerts show up, right ?

Comment: Yes the alert show up. If it is success then it alert success. If it is error, it alerts the error message. The problem is in both condition it redirect it to the `window location`.

Comment: Then something else is redirecting. If the `else` statement executes, and you see an alert that doesn't say `success`, there's no way the code enters the `if` condition and redirects.

Comment: Can you show the form html as well?

Comment: Nope, I just solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solve my problem :

```
   if ($.trim(html) === "SUCCESS")
```

the problem is because there is white-space between them, eventhough I don't know where the white space comes from.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the window.location in the success IF.  I bet it still redirects.  Does the form that creates this data have an action on it?  Is that action? infistallLocation.php?

I bet your ajax is submitting AND your form is submitting.  You only want the ajax.

You need to prevent the default form from submitting

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var frm = $('#yourformID');
frm.submit(function (ev) {
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "../actions/memberStock-ajax.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success:function(html)
        {
            if (html=='success')
                {
                alert (html);
                window.location='infistallLocation.php'
                }

            else {
                alert (html);
                //Just stay here, don't go anywhere/ 
                }
        }
    }); 

    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the form doesn't have the action. And also I have put a `preventDefault()`; in the ajax before the `$.ajax(` function.

Comment: It doesn't redirect if I remove the window location.

Comment: Okay. Can we see more code?  The form and the ajax javascript together?